# Replace space with %20 in r

Tags: r, replace

I have following string:

```
url <- https://www.google.mu/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=green carot
```

I want to replace the space between green and carot with %20

```
>url
https://www.google.mu/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=green%20carot
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a straight string replacement use:

```
> gsub(" ", "%20", url)
```

Though, a URL encode function like `URLencode()` would be better.

Answer (score 10):

there are some functions to work with url. 
In base R use `URLencode`

```r
url <- "https://www.google.mu/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=green carot"

URLencode(url)
#> [1] "https://www.google.mu/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=green%20carot"
```